# shared element transaction not working with recyclerview when more than one element

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition

there is a recyclerview in android application and i want shared element transaction when user goes to other fragment for that I tried as mentioned below code.

**image view in row xml file**

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_album_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:transitionName="image_transit"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    android:src="@drawable/img_default"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

**image view in second fragment**

```
<ImageView
    android:id='@+id/iv_album_thumbnail'
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:transitionName="image_transit"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,UnusedAttribute"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
```

**on click method**

```
public void onAlbumClicked(RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    SongListFragment kittenDetails = SongListFragment.newInstance(aList.get(position));

    // Note that we need the API version check here because the actual transition classes (e.g. Fade)
    // are not in the support library and are only available in API 21+. The methods we are calling on the Fragment
    // ARE available in the support library (though they don't do anything on API < 21)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        kittenDetails.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new DetailsTransition());
        kittenDetails.setEnterTransition(new Fade());
        setExitTransition(new Fade());
        kittenDetails.setSharedElementReturnTransition(new DetailsTransition());
    }

    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .addSharedElement(holder.imgPicture, "image_transit")
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)
            .replace(R.id.root, kittenDetails)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

when there is only one item in `recyclerview` it is working perfect but when there is more than one item in `recyclerview` there is no effect at all, can anyone please currant me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have multiple views having the same transition name in the source view tree.

You should set it only on clicked row :

- remove the `android:transitionName` attribute from the row xml.
- add `ViewCompat.SetTransitionName(holder.imgPicture, "image_transit");`

Comment: Thank you @bwt but can you please tell me whee should I add  `SetTransitionName` in my code ?

Comment: I would put it inside the `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {` block